# PHP Fill with values an existing .xlsb file with data from Oracle

Tags: php, oracle

I want to write into my .xlsb Excel file which has a name that is the number of the day.
For example the name of the file for yesterday is `23.xlsb`.

Initial the name of the file is "Template.xlsb" and the location is different. As you can see this file it's copied and renamed in a new location. In this file I have a lot of macros and VBA codes and that's why I don't want to create a new Excel file.

At the end, the link for this Excel file is in this variable `$renamed_link`.
`$renamed_link = C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\Rezultate DIDU\2017\Apr\23.xlsb`.

I want to fill the first worksheet, named "Parametri" with data from my SQL query(`$parametri`).
The range from worksheet which will be filled with data is from `A2` until `T and the total number of the rows`. The table has 20 columns.

```
<?php
require(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)."/PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel.php"));
$sql_data = date('d.m.Y', strtotime('-1days'));

    $conn = oci_connect('USER', 'PASS', 'dark:1521/DAR');
    if (!$conn) {
        $e = oci_error();
        trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
    }
    Else {echo 'Connection successfully !';
    }
$parametri = oci_parse($conn,"SELECT * FROM R0508UNITP WHERE TO_DATE('${sql_data}','DD.MM.YYYY') BETWEEN R0508UNITP.R0508VFROM AND R0508UNITP.R0508VTILL");

oci_execute($parametri);

echo "<table border='1'>\n";
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($parametri, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {


echo "<tr>\n";
foreach ($row as $item) {
    echo "    <td>" . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : "&nbsp;") . "</td>\n";
}
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";

$day = date('j', strtotime('-1 days'));
$month = date('M', strtotime('-1 days'));
$year = date('Y', strtotime('-1 days'));


$link = "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\Rezultate DIDU\\${year}\\${month}";
$template_link = 'C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\Rezultate DIDU\Template.xlsb';
$destination_link = "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\Rezultate DIDU\\${year}\\${month}".'\Template.xlsb';
$renamed_link = "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\Rezultate DIDU\\${year}\\${month}\\${day}".'.xlsb';


if(!is_dir($link)) 
{

mkdir($link, 0777,true);

}

if(!file_exists($destination_link))
{
    copy($template_link,$destination_link);
    
} else {
}

rename($destination_link,$renamed_link);
?>
```

Print screen of my PHP table(some of it).
This table I want to be in my Excel file.
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Parsing and (especially) editing and **xlsb** (miscrosoft excel binary file) is not trivial at all.

At the time of writing you can find the ~1000 pages format specification pdf at this link: http://interoperability.blob.core.windows.net/files/MS-XLSB/[MS-XLSB].pdf

To avoid **xlsb** complexity there are PHP libraries that let you manipulate those files:

**EasyXLS** is a commercial solution:

https://www.easyxls.com/

Another option is **PHPExcel**

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

it's licensed under LGPL. This library let you write (among the others) `BIFF 8 (.xls) Excel 95 and above` files. You should check if your **xlsb** files fall under this category.

---

As you've fetched the data from the db (you already succeeded in doing this) then inserting that data into the **xlsb** template file and saving as a new file is trivial. Both libraries offer examples and tutorials.

Just one of them: https://www.easyxls.com/manual/tutorials/php/read-xlsb-file.html

---

### **UPDATE**

As written above **EasyXLS** can read **xlsb** files whose internal format is **BIFF12**.

This is stated on their website, I didn't tested actually their software but there is a "trial version" available for download so you may give it a try.

**EasyXLS** is not free and is around $295 at the time of writing so may be out of budget depending on your project.

**EasyXLS** is not a pure PHP library: the **.NET** version comes with a [COM+ Library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) with support for PHP (among other languages). For this reason it's not suitable ***nix** systems but as you're on **Windows** it could be a viable solution.

---

### Let's see **PHPExcel**

Development of this library has been abandoned in favour of the the new **[PhpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet)**

The latter is still in a development stage. The current release however is almost complete and usable and I would expect a production / stable release to be available soon.

**PhpSpreadsheet** supports **BIFF5** and **BIFF8** formats that are the files with extension **.xls**.

It does **not** support **BIFF12** - **.xlsb** files.

---

### Testing **PHPSpreadsheet**

The [documentation](http://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/) is very clear and thorough.

I downloaded and installed the current release with [Composer](https://getcomposer.org) following the instructions available in the documentation.

I "downgraded" the **Template.xlsb** file you provided to **.xls** format (using Excel). Apparently I didn't lose any of the functionality of the original file.

Then I was able to edit it with the following code...

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xls();
$spreadsheet = $reader->load( 'Template.xls' );

$worksheet = $spreadsheet->getSheetByName( 'PARAMETRI' );

$worksheet->setCellValue( 'A2', 123 );

$writer = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xls( $spreadsheet );
$writer->save( "Template-Modified.xls" );
```

...but the saved file `Template-Modified.xls` **has lost the macros**.

However running the same code on another **.xls** file I made with macros **succeeded** in the process **without loosing anything**.

Probably the macros on your file get lost as they are **password protected** in the source file.

---

I think with minor compromises you may succeed in your project with **PHPSpreadsheet**.

I don't know if you can downgrade to **.xls** and / or remove password protection from macros in your template files.

Anyway **PHPSpreadsheet** development is very active, the documentation and code is good.

You may get further informations or support directly from the development team via **GitHub**

Comment: Hi Paolo, For EasyXLS must be paid and for PHPExcel Library I have not found anything about .xlsb file. My xlsb file have this format 
 `(BIFF12) for Excel 2007-2013`.

Comment: @Marius yes, EasyXLS must be paid, that is what I meant when I wrote "commercial solution". As for PHPExcel maybe your `BIFF12` files use only a subset of the format features and can be edited as `BIFF8`. I would give it a try. If you put somewhere one of your **xlsb** files (purged from any sensitive info) and give me the link I may give it a try.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I put the file here:

 ` https://wetransfer.com/downloads/51babe5bb26d6ae5e73486a9ba0a318520170502053547/b988faf6e55669f9b3948d9c795092b320170502053547/d75c24`

Comment: Thank you for your support. I will try to use `.xls` file and create a macro in `template.xlsb` to import data from that file. I think this is the easiest way.

Comment: EasyXLS for .NET includes COM+ library

Comment: @alex.pulver I understand now what you intend. I'll give a look and update the answer. Thank you.